# Are awards ever subsequently revised based on new developments, other than divorce cases?

Tags: united-states, defamation

In a divorce case, alimony may be subsequently modified either up or down, based on the changes in financial circumstances of either the payor (usually the husband) or the recipient (usually the wife).

Can changes in the underlying circumstances change awards, *outside of divorce*?
There are a number of possible situations, but I'll use the one that I am most familiar with, defamation.

In the 1979 case [Bindrim vs. Mitchell](http://www.casebriefs.com/blog/law/torts/torts-keyed-to-epstein/defamation/bindrim-v-mitchell/), a plaintiff, Paul Bindrim, won an award against novelist Gwen Mitchell and her publisher Doubleday for "defaming" him in connection a novel, purportedly fiction, about his "signature" nude therapy treatment. (Although Mitchell had taken pains to disguise Bindrim, his treatment was so unique that it identified him.)

Suppose Bidrim's therapy business took off after the novel and/or lawsuit so that the increase in his annual income exceeded the award. Is there any legal mechanism to reduce or reverse the award, since the publication actually increased, rather than decreased, his "fame and fortune"?

One of the grounds for the award was that Mitchell had "defamed" him (in the 1970s) by "misquoting" him as telling people to grab women by their private parts (which he never said). A recently elected President of the United States actually used a very similar term. Suppose, instead, that the sitting 1980 Presidential candidate (who admitted to Playboy magazine to "committing adultery in his heart") had expressed this idea, thereby "popularizing" the concept. Is there any legal mechanism to reduce the award on the grounds that it's no longer defamatory if a POTUS uses it?